# Erro de conversão "Array to string conversion" no PHP 7

Tags: php

Tentei revisar um pouco, porem em todas as vezes que passo por ele não consigo enxergar o erro cometido. O erro do notice é :

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in ../library/DAO.php on line 781
```

E a função em que ele aponta é:

```
private function setObjFromSqlWithId($result, DTO $dto) {
        $objArray = array();
        if ($result) {
            foreach ($result as $linha) {
                $dto = null;
                foreach ($linha as $key => $value) {
                    $object = $this->objectsSql[$key];
                    if ($dto == null)
                        $dto = new $object[0]();
                    $dto->$object[1]($value);
                }
                $objArray[] = clone $dto;
            }
        }
        else {
            return array();
        }
        return $objArray;
    }
```

Pode ser que pela a alteração de versão do PHP tenha mudado algo porem não consigo achar. Por favor se alguém souber me ajude.

Erro que aparece um pouco abaixo:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string in .../library/DAO.php:781 Stack trace: #0 .../library/DAO.php(751): DAO->setObjFromSqlWithId(Array, Object(Usuario)) #1 .../library/DAO.php(189): DAO->execSql('\tSELECT id as i...', Object(Usuario)) #2 .../persistencia/UsuarioDAO.php(15): DAO->getByPk(Object(Usuario), '8') #3 .../controle/ControlLogin.php(29): UsuarioDAO->getDTO('8') #4 .../library/Controller.php(266): ControlLogin->home() #5 .../library/Controller.php(305): Controller->listener() #6 .../index_01.php(31): Controller->loadModule() #7 {main} thrown in .../library/DAO.php on line 781
```

Comment: Não é problema com a versão. Qual é a linha do erro?

Comment: $dto->$object[1]($value);

Comment: Meu palpites `$object` é uma string então o `[1]` está batendo em um caracter.

Comment: Entendo, editei com o fatal error que aparece, mas não estou conseguindo interpretar o erro

Comment: Manda imprir o `$dto->$object[1]` ou dá um `var_dump()`. Veja se sintaxa esta correta `$dto->$object` e ` $dto->object` são coisa diferentes.

Comment: Já havia tentado ver se era sintaxe o notice some porem o fatal error continua na mesma linha

Comment: O falta error diz que foi passado um array no lugar de uma string para fazer a chamada do método. Precisa analisar o valor de `$object`

Comment: Se eu dou echo nele, ele me imprime UsuariogetId

Comment: Todas as vezes?

Comment: Sim, eu colocando o echo dentro do for ele imprime o UsuariogetId